# apt-get update 404

Tags: apt, ubuntu-9.10

`apt-get update` yields a 404 error.

I'm using the default mirrors for for Ubuntu 9.10. That version hasn't reached end of life yet so I don't see why this would be happening.

Comment: Providing your /etc/apt/sources.list would be a good start :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually Ubuntu 9.10 *is* EOL. It went EOL on [April 30th, 2011](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) you can update by changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

Comment: agh crumbs, I'm still in 2011 mode. That explains a lot. Saw the EOL date and thought "2 more months I should be fine"